# How do you define and call a function in Spacemacs?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I've defined a emacs / lisp function within `defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()` like so:

```
(defun clientdir ()
"docstring"
neotree-dir "~/Projects/Clients"
)
```

How do I execute it?

Comment: You would call it like usually on Emacs :) see [elisp in 15 minutes - interactive functions](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Emacs_Lisp_in_15_minutes#Interactive_functions) and [other ressources](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Category:Emacs_Lisp), hope that helps !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That function will evaluate the `neotree-dir` variable and discard the result, then evaluate the `"~/Projects/Clients"` string and return it.

i.e. Your function unconditionally returns the value `"~/Projects/Clients"` (unless `neotree-dir` is not bound as a variable, in which case it will trigger an error).

I am *guessing* that you wanted to call a function called `neotree-dir` and pass it `"~/Projects/Clients"` as an argument? That would look like this: `(neotree-dir "~/Projects/Clients")`

If you want to call the function *interactively* you must declare it as an `interactive` function:

```el
(defun clientdir ()
  "Invoke `neotree-dir' on ~/Projects/Clients"
  (interactive)
  (neotree-dir "~/Projects/Clients"))
```

You can then call it with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `clientdir` <kbd>RET</kbd>, or bind it to a key sequence, etc...