# How do i create my own function in spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs

I have switched over to Spacemacs but some function is not working anymore.

I am trying to run a function to [create a time range from effort estimate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044588/org-mode-creation-time-range-from-effort-estimate) Create by lawlist

```html
(defun org-schedule-effort ()
(interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (org-back-to-heading t)
    (let* (
        (element (org-element-at-point))
        (effort (org-element-property :EFFORT element))
        (scheduled (org-element-property :scheduled element))
        (ts-year-start (org-element-property :year-start scheduled))
        (ts-month-start (org-element-property :month-start scheduled))
        (ts-day-start (org-element-property :day-start scheduled))
        (ts-hour-start (org-element-property :hour-start scheduled))
        (ts-minute-start (org-element-property :minute-start scheduled)) )
      (org-schedule nil (concat
        (format "%s" ts-year-start)
        "-"
        (if (< ts-month-start 10)
          (concat "0" (format "%s" ts-month-start))
          (format "%s" ts-month-start))
        "-"
        (if (< ts-day-start 10)
          (concat "0" (format "%s" ts-day-start))
          (format "%s" ts-day-start))
        " "
        (if (< ts-hour-start 10)
          (concat "0" (format "%s" ts-hour-start))
          (format "%s" ts-hour-start))
        ":"
        (if (< ts-minute-start 10)
          (concat "0" (format "%s" ts-minute-start))
          (format "%s" ts-minute-start))
        "+"
        effort)) )))
```

But when I run `M-x org-schedule-effort` the function is not found

I understand that you would [call it like usually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042620/how-do-you-define-and-call-a-function-in-spacemacs) as it works in Emacs

I have place all the functions in  `defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()` and tested with a hello world script

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
    (defun say-hello ()
        "hello")
)
```

How do I run a defun in Spacemacs?